How to prevent an app clearing its own data
How to prevent an app clearing its own data . Thats the 3rd time WhatsApp deleted its own data against Users wish. There can be a zillon reasons which I don't care . If the user does not clear data - then the data should be there.
Is there anyway to implement that ? If I am rooted how about if I do this :
busybox chattr +a +u /data/data/com.whatsapp

You can append but cant delete files. will the app crash ? what happens. I want to ask before crashing anything that works.
what if you do just +u
u set : When such a file is deleted, its data is saved enabling the user to ask for its undeletion.

In the latter case , if the app were to del. its data , I'd be able to restore it ?
P.S. this is not your internal storage f2fs but its an ext4 file system  since the  data  folder is linked to my SD card Partition.

I don't think that this will work. Databases like SQLite create temporary files when opened and delete them when closed. Better make backup so you may be able to restore data. And avoid the scenarios where Whatsapp deletes your data (usually apps don't delete their data without a reason, otherwise this would be a bug).

A more fundamental issue here is that Android doesn't really control what apps do, it just gives them specific permissions to do (or not) do things... One things apps are explicitly allowed to do is have their own file "space" and control over their own files, read, write, edit, and delete, within their own context... I don't know of anyway you could prevent that and keep the app functional.

Android is  a  'hypercustom' Linux .  The command is available. I tried some scenarios myself I can add files to a dir. I can append data to a file but I cant delete it - but the Q I had was  how  WhatsApp ( WA  ) modifies msgstore.db in its internal data. If it adds records without creating an open file handle it will work . If it has to open the file , modify & close it will not allow it. I wonder what situation will apply
